# eliminar clases de con Jquery de forma secuencial

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola amigos tengo múltiples botones con una misma clase, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le de un click a cualquier botón me agregue una clase, pero que también me quite la clase que trae los demás botones  sin quitar la clase del botón que había seleccionado,
seria una gran ayuda de que me puedan dar indicios de como puedo hacer esto muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes leer [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), luego, si tienes problemas con algo del código, vuelves y redactas una pregunta que cumpla con el formato del sitio. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con el siguiente código.

`onClickButton` es un handler que quita la classe (`buttonToggleClass`) de todos los botones e al final la pone en el que fue clicado. Este handler es utilizado después para registrar listeners para todos los botones (`registerButtonClickEventListener`), o sea, siempre que hagas click en uno de los botones, el handler es executado.

El css lo puedes ignorar. Apenas lo puse para que puedas visualmente distinguir el botón que tiene la classe aplicada a cada momento.

```js
const buttonSelector = '.btn';
const buttonToggleClass = 'btn-selected';
const buttonElements = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

const onClickButton = (button) => {
  buttonElements.forEach((buttonElement) => {
    buttonElement.classList.remove(buttonToggleClass);
  });
  
  button.classList.add(buttonToggleClass);
}

const registerButtonClickEventListener = () => {
  buttonElements.forEach((buttonElement) => {
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => onClickButton(event.target));
  });
};

registerButtonClickEventListener();
```

```css
.btn-selected {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button A</button>
<button class="btn">Button B</button>
<button class="btn">Button C</button>
```

Comment: Evita responder preguntas mal formuladas. Terminan cerradas y tu aporte se pierde. Por otro lado, el OP pide usar JQuery, no veo que lo uses en tu respuesta. Saludos